# Setting ListView.GroupStyle in XAML dynamically?

Tags: wpf, listview, groupstyle

I've got a ListView, whose View is switched dynamically in runtime between an Icon mode and a Grid mode (the latter implemented with a GridView).
The problem is, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404303/wpf-listview-icons-view-shown-in-a-single-column), that when I add ListView.GroupStyle in my ListView definition, the Icon mode gets screwed. Hence, I'd like to reset/disable GroupStyle for that mode.

So, my question: **is there a way to apply/reset the GroupStyle dynamically (via a Trigger?)** when I switch the ListView into the Grid mode?

I tried to do that (e.g. `<Setter Property="ListView.GroupStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>`) for the Icon View, but this doesn't compile because "The Property Setter 'GroupStyle' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor."

Any suggestions will be cordially welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

There could be two ways to do this...

1. Instead of setting the `GroupStyle` to `x:Null` keep the existing set `GroupStyle` as it is, but reset its inner template using `DataTrigger`s that use `TemplateBinding`.
2. Use bottom up approach, remove your `GroupDescriptions` from your `CollectionView` based on the mode.

Comment: AngelWPF, thank you for the answer.
The second approach wouldn't work for me since the problem is with the GroupStyle definition itself (even when there are no GroupDescriptions at all).
As for the first one - I am not sure I'm following... Could you please give a code snippet to illustrate what you mean?